# Unable to see resharper pop-ups for Ctrl-N and other similar commands

Tags: types, filter, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper-5.0

I'm not able to see the resharper pop-ups for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and other similar commands but other resharper shortcuts work fine - rename, stack explorer, run unit tests etc...

Using `Resharper 5.0 beta`. Tried uninstalling and re-installing as well, Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:
Forgot to add that I can see the popups when there are no tabs (no file), but I don't see it when there's at least 1 file (or tab) open in VS.

Answer (score 9):

Well... in my case while using [ReShaper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) 8.2 I had to click `RESHARPER` menu in Visual Studio then select `Options...` in `Keyboard & Menus => Keyboard Shortcuts` select `ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA`. Click `Apply Scheme` then `Save`. It did it for me.

I had `Visual Studio` selected in `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> [Go to Everything/Type](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Type.html) now works beautifully and I can start typing to get a filtered list of matching files. Sweet! :)

[image]

Comment: one thing to note: you need to do this even if you open this menu and the ReSharper theme is already selected. In my case, when I originally installed ReSharper I chose their keyboard scheme and it worked no problem. Then later down the road I reset a couple of Visual Studio settings and then the scheme stopped working for me. I went into this menu and the ReSharper scheme was still selected but was not working. For me to fix it I actually had to click the "Apply Scheme" button again after changing the unrelated settings even though I had already clicked the button when I installed ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

1. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > <kbd>Reset</kbd>
2. Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus, select **Resharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA** and then press <kbd>Apply Scheme</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

try to reset key bindings - it works for me.
here is how to do [that](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5248892)

Comment: try another build. I tried a lot to find usable build :). and in one of latest build I saw described bug.

Comment: actually I did. I tried beta and then i tried the latest build. I'm not sure if its related to R# or VS itself.

Comment: also cleaning resharper cache can help. it is located in options or simply delete all resharper related folders and files

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ keyboard and shortcut settings and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the shortcut manually worked for me. (Vs 2018)

Visual studio > Options >Environment >Keyboard. Type Resharper.Resharper_GotoType on the command filter box and select the comand. Add your preferred shortcuts (in my case Ctrl+N) and click assign button. then Ok.